# Tomcat + RichFaces 4.1 exceptions when loading file

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tomcat7

I have deployed my webapp but for some reason, some exceptions appear when trying to load files into server, I don't know why is this happening. Sometimes when I try to upload a file the `rich:fileUpload` doesn't upload the file, the progress bar of the component never gets filled and an exception like the following appears on Tomcat's log:

```
may 21, 2012 8:38:04 PM org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25 parseIfNecessary
SEVERE: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1339)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.calculateRenderKitId(MultiViewHandler.java:220)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.calculateRenderKitId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.isPostback(FacesContextImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.isPostback(FacesContextWrapper.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
    ... 30 more

may 21, 2012 8:38:04 PM org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25 parseIfNecessary
SEVERE: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1339)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.calculateRenderKitId(MultiViewHandler.java:220)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.calculateRenderKitId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.isPostback(FacesContextImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.isPostback(FacesContextWrapper.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
    ... 33 more

may 21, 2012 8:38:04 PM org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25 parseIfNecessary
SEVERE: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1339)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.calculateRenderKitId(MultiViewHandler.java:220)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.calculateRenderKitId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.isPostback(FacesContextImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.isPostback(FacesContextWrapper.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
    ... 30 more

may 21, 2012 8:38:04 PM org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25 parseIfNecessary
SEVERE: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
    at com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1339)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.calculateRenderKitId(MultiViewHandler.java:220)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.calculateRenderKitId(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.isPostback(FacesContextImpl.java:211)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.isPostback(FacesContextWrapper.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1824)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
    at org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
    ... 33 more
```

Any idea on what could be happening? Where can I start looking for fixing this on my app?

CHeers,

Comment: This seems a library compatibility problem: 
see https://community.jboss.org/message/633568

Comment: Did you resolve this? Plz let me know. Tnx.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same stacktrace in my project. I can explain why this is happening and few ways to fix it.

So richfaces fileUpload component assumes that multipart request InputStream was not yet read from other places. But if you have in your application any filter that executes simple 
`request.getParameter(anyParamName)` this forces multipart request to read full inputstream and put everything into `request.getParts()` collection.

When richfaces fileupload attempts to read something from inputstream it cannot do it because the stream cursor is at the end(this is in tomcat sources) and just returns -1; This causes richfaces to think that it can not read anything from the stream.

To fix this you can remove all filters that force multipart request to parse inputStream.
Also as a hot fix you can try to alter some of the richfaces classes like `MultipartRequest25` or `MultipartRequestParser`.

I have added hot fix to `MultipartRequestParser` in order to check if request already has Parts and attempt to parse there parts into FileUploadParam. This is quite hacky checking the message of the exception but it can work as a hot fix.

There exists non resolved issue in jboss jira that seems to be about this issue. You can check it out. I was adding a comment there too. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13061

```
public void parse() throws FileUploadException {
    try {
        initialize();

        while (!sequenceMatcher.isEOF()) {
            readNext();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if(e.getMessage().equals(REQUEST_PROLOG_CANNOT_BE_READ)){
            //means it can not read request prolog. maybe application server already read everything and stores data in parts
            try {
                if(request.getParts()!=null && request.getParts().size()>0){
                    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
                    //parts seem to be complete files so get the headers and so on here
                    //and create fileUploadItems from parts
                    for(Part part:parts){
                        String headersString = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
                        Multimap<String, String> headers = LinkedListMultimap.create();
                        String[] split = headersString.split("\r\n");
                        for (String headerString : split) {
                            parseParams(headerString, "; ", headers);
                        }
                        FileUploadParam param = createParam(headers);
                        if (param == null) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        param.create();
                        try{
                            int size = (int)part.getSize();
                            byte[] buf = new byte[size];
                            part.getInputStream().read(buf, 0, size);
                            param.handle(buf, size);
                        }finally{
                            param.complete();
                        }

                        if (param.isFileParam()) {
                            uploadedFiles.add(new UploadedFile25(param.getName(), param.getResource(), headers));
                        } else {
                            parametersMap.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                    //return from the method if everything was successfull
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                this.cancel();
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could get Parts from the request", e1);
            }
        }
        this.cancel();
        throw new FileUploadException(MessageFormat.format("Exception parsing multipart request: {0}", e.getMessage()), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you give us a concrete example for "remove all filters that force multipart request to parse inputStream"?

Comment: Probably this is late to answer your question, but I was meaning that when you have a filter chain that intercept your request and some of the filters in this chain call request.getParameter('someParam') it forces app server to read inputstream of multipart request and after that cursor of inputstrean remain at the end. So you can just make sure that you have no filters that intercept your request and call request.getParameter() or request.getParameterMap methods.